# What does this obfuscated bash/perl code do?

Tags: perl, bash, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I've just found this code in a comment on a blog.

```
#!/bin/perl -sp0777i<X+d*lMLa^*lN%0]dsXx++lMlN/dsM0<j]dsj
$/=unpack('H*',$_);$_=`echo 16dio\U$k"SK$/SM$n\EsN0p[lN*1
lK[d2%Sa2/d0$^Ixp"|dc`;s/\W//g;$_=pack('H*',/((..)*)$/)
```

I realise it's probably a bad idea to paste this into the terminal, but can someone untangle this and tell me what it's meant to do? I'm not even sure it's valid code :)

Comment: It would be interesting to look at blog post, could you give a link?

Comment: Should migrate to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Great, now I have a headache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it here http://www.cypherspace.org/adam/rsa/ and it's said that it's

> a perl program which implements RSA encryption and decryption,
>   and is small enough to use as a signature file

and [here](http://www.cypherspace.org/adam/rsa/story2.html) is the full explanation of the code - it uses **dc** (GNU desk calculator by the way).